# match pages corresponding to the wikipedia content from the wikipedia sql dumps

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, dump, wikipedia-api

Referring to the description:

###### Wikipedia:Contents categorises types of articles in Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contents

I want to extract all of the articles referring to types of contents, like Outlines, Lists. These articles are in the same namespace as normal articles, so filtering pages by namespace did not work.

I looked at info at:

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/What%27s_available_for_download

and at `content` and `content models` tables in :
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Content_models_table

but I could not find a way to solve the problem.

- How could I extract the pageids, or titles, of the pages that belongs to types of content as Outline and List, mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contents ?
- Which Dumps contains such info ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this query at [Quarry](https://quarry.wmcloud.org/) which I think does what you're asking:

```
SELECT page_title,page_id from page
Where (page_title LIKE 'List_%' 
    OR page_title LIKE 'Outline_%')
and page_is_redirect = 0
and page_namespace = 0
```

You can see the results here: https://quarry.wmcloud.org/query/71439

Comment: Thanks @smartse, I did not know about quarry, that's interesting. So basically there are no tags for types of content, only based on title name patterns ?

Comment: Does quarry has an API, that is possibly to use it without installing wikipedia dumps, and retrieve results on own system?

Comment: To Q1 - yes unless you start looking at categories like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists in which case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:PetScan might be useful.

To Q2 - no unfortunately not.